# Click individual selections from a button

Tags: manipulate, button

I have a graphic where each `Arrow`, `Rectangle`, and `Text` is a `Button`. If any of these elements are clicked on it will turn blue and the number of selected `Rectangles` and `Arrows` **will be counted**.

When an `Arrow` is clicked on more `Text` will appear below that `Arrow`. This `Text` can also be clicked on.

I have been able to get all of this to work except for one important detail: when an `Arrow`/stream (`A`, `B`, `C`, or `D`) is clicked on and `Subscript[a,i]`, `Subscript[b,i]`, `Subscript[c,i]`, or `Subscript[d,i]` (where `i` ranges from 1 to 3) is shown, I want to be able to click on one of these new selections individually...

For example: I click on stream `A` and `Subscript[a,1]`, `Subscript[a,2]`, and `Subscript[a,3]` show up. I want to be able to click on `Subscript[a,1]` but not `Subscript[a,2]` or `Subscript[a,3]` (or some other combination) so the one I click turns blue.

Currently if I click one, all three turn blue.

[image]

Here is the code I've been using:

```
Manipulate[
 Module[{comp, equipment, streams},
  comp[label_, pos_] := 
   Text[Style[Subscript[label, #], 15], pos, {0, #*2}] & /@ 
    Range@species;

  equipment = {
    {"unit 1", Rectangle[{2, 0}, {4, 2}], Text["unit 1", {3, 1}]},
    {"unit 2", Rectangle[{6, 0}, {8, 2}], Text["unit 2", {7, 1}]}
    };

  streams = {
    {"A", Arrow[{{-1, 1}, {2, 1}}], Text["A", {0, 1}, {0, -1}], 
     comp["a", {0, 1}]},
    {"B", Arrow[{{4, 1}, {6, 1}}], Text["B", {5, 1}, {0, -1}], 
     comp["b", {5, 1}]},
    {"C", Arrow[{{8, 1}, {10, 1}}], Text["C", {9, 1}, {0, -1}], 
     comp["c", {9, 1}]},
    {"D", Arrow[{{7, 0}, {7, -1}, {1, -1}, {1, 1}}], 
     Text["D", {4, -1}, {0, -1}], comp["d", {4, -1}]}
    };

  Graphics[{
    {FaceForm[Transparent],
     If[FreeQ[e, #[[1]]],
        Button[{EdgeForm[Thick], #[[2]], Style[#[[3]], 16]}, 
         AppendTo[e, #[[1]]]],
        Button[{EdgeForm[{Thick, Blue}], #[[2]], 
          Style[#[[3]], 16, Bold, Blue]}, e = DeleteCases[e, #[[1]]]]
        ] & /@ equipment
     },
    {Thick,
     If[FreeQ[s, #],
        Button[{#[[2]], Style[#[[3]], 16]}, AppendTo[s, #]],
        Button[{Blue, #[[2]], Style[#[[3]], 16, Bold]}, 
         s = DeleteCases[s, #]]
        ] & /@ streams
     },

    Map[If[FreeQ[c, #],
       Button[#[[4]], AppendTo[c, #]],
       Button[Style[#[[4]], Bold, Blue], c = DeleteCases[c, #]]
       ] &, s]

    }, ImageSize -> 500]
  ],
 Control[{{species, 3, "number of species"}, {2, 3, 4}, Setter}],
 Control[{{e, {}}, ControlType -> None}],
 Control[{{s, {}}, ControlType -> None}],
 Control[{{c, {}}, ControlType -> None}]
 ]
```

I have tried to separate each `Subscript[j,i]` button without success.

Answer (score 2):

There really is no question in your post. I'll assume you are asking what is going wrong but not expecting to get free code to fix it.

A call to `comp` returns a list of subscripted lowercase letters which you insert into one of rows of `streams`. When one of the labels is clicked on, the whole list of subscripted lowercase letters associated with that label is made into ***one*** button. You will have to map `Button` over the list of subscripted lowercase letters to get such letters to act independently.

BTW, the control specifications in your `Manipulate` can be simplified to

```
{{species, 3, "number of species"}, {2, 3, 4}, Setter}, 
{{e, {}}, None},
{{s, {}}, None},
{{c, {}}, None}
```